# access value (content) of a named cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, reference

This

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("foo\bar.xlsx", , True)
Debug.Print (WB.Names("named_cell").Value)
WB.Close (False)
```

returns

```
='Sheet'!$C$377
```

instead of the value in the cell `C377`.

How can I receive the value of the cell instead?

Comment: Try `Debug.Print (WB.Worksheets("NameOfSheet").Range("named_cell").Value)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! This works. However, it's a bit strange that I can access the reference of a named range without specifying the sheet name but not the content... Is there really no way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `WB.Names("named_cell")` returns a `Name` object, then this object has a `RefersToRange` property. That returns the Range object referred to by a Name object. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834918.aspx.

So

```
Debug.Print WB.Names("named_cell").RefersToRange.Value
```

See also [Malfunction of Excel-VBA own function when open other excel-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604412/malfunction-of-excel-vba-own-function-when-open-other-excel-file/32606967#32606967).

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Couple of ways:

```
Debug.Print Range("Named_Range").Value
Debug.Print [Named_Range].Value '// This uses the evaluate method
```

You don't need to qualify a named range with a sheet object if it's in the active workbook (which it should be as it's the last workbook you opened).

Answer (score 2):

Once the Named Range has been established, Excel knows its `Parent`, so:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("named_cell")
    MsgBox r.Parent.Name & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & r.Value
End Sub
```

is one way to get info about this range:

[image]

This uses the properties of the *Range* Object rather than the *Workbook* Object.